Solve or find a sharper lower bound for $\int_{1}^t \frac{x^v}{\beta^x} \ \mathrm{d}x$
I'm trying to solve the following problem by providing a asymptotically sharper lower bound.


For $t\ge1$, $v\le 0$, and $\beta \in (0,1)$, solve, or find a lower bound for, the integral $$\int_{1}^t \frac{x^v}{\beta^x} \ \mathrm{d}x.$$


I'm struggling to get a meaningful closed form for the lower bound, so I'm wondering if anybody has any approaches or interesting ideas that can induce a sharper bound. For example, as $x^v/\beta^x$ is eventually increasing for $x$ large, I suppose a lower bound could be $(t-1)^v/\beta^{t-1}$, where I just let $x=t-1$ into the integrand, while assuming we are in the increasing region of the integrand ($t$ would need to be sufficiently large for this to hold). Would sharper, and cleaner, closed form lower bounds exist? Or is there a trick to solve the integral above that I am missing?

By applying integration by parts, we obtain
$$
\int_1^t x^v \beta^{-x} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{t^v \beta^{-t} - \beta^{-1}}{|\log \beta|} + \frac{|v|}{|\log \beta|} \int_1^t x^{v-1} \beta^{-x} \mathrm{d}x \geq \frac{t^v \beta^{-t} - \beta^{-1}}{|\log \beta|}
$$
for $t \geq 1$, $v \leq 0$, and $\beta \in (0, 1)$. This estimate is asymptotically sharp, as we can see by applying L'Hôpital's rule:
$$
\lim_{t \to+ \infty} \frac{\int_1^t x^v \beta^{-x} \mathrm{d}x}{t^v \beta^{-t} - \beta^{-1}} = \lim_{t \to+ \infty} \frac{t^v \beta^{-t}}{v t^{v-1} \beta^{-t} + |\log \beta| t^v \beta^{-t}} = \lim_{t \to+ \infty} \frac{1}{v t^{-1} + |\log \beta|} = \frac{1}{|\log \beta|}.
$$

Using the incomplete gamma function
$$I=\int \frac{x^v}{\beta^x} \,dx=-\log ^{-(v+1)}(\beta )\,\, \Gamma (v+1,x \log (\beta )))$$For the definite integral
$$J=\int_1^t \frac{x^v}{\beta^x} \,dx$$ using the exponential integral function
$$\large\color{blue}{J=E_{-v}(\log (\beta ))-t^{v+1}\,\, E_{-v}(t \log (\beta ))}$$
